# SLF4J: print variable twice into log message

Tags: java, logging

How could I create a log message containing a value twice?

For example:

```
log.error("Request '{}' not found! Add this <request name=\"{}\"> into the xml file.", requestName);
```

Without using `String.format` and his ugly pattern `%$1s`.

Comment: `log.error("Request '{}' not found! Add this <request name=\"{}\"> into the xml file.", requestName, requestName);` why not like that?

Comment: Because is less ugly than using `String.format`, but still ugly :)

Comment: It doesn't seem possible because slf4j uses '{}' as a formatting anchor and doesn't allow to reference parameters by name/position (https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html). You have to use https://www.slf4j.org/localization.html to be able to use java.text.MessageFormat parameter substitution. I would just rephrase the message.